# How to insert big data in SQLite in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to insert a big data in SQLite like spinner selected item , date time, and string. When I run the app I got:

> SQLite exception : No Such Table while compiling for insert into. database

I don't know how to do.

Here is database Code

```
public class DataBase_Adapter 
{

        //Database NAme
        static final String DATABASE_NAME = "lead_management.db";

        //Database Version
        static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


        // Variable to hold the database instance
        public  SQLiteDatabase db;

        // Context of the application using the database.
        private final Context context;

        // Database open/upgrade helper
        private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

        public  DataBase_Adapter(Context _context) 
        {
            context = _context;
            dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public  DataBase_Adapter open() throws SQLException 
        {
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        public void close() 
        {
            db.close();
        }

        public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
        {
            return db;
        }

        //Table name
    static final String TABLE_NEW_LEAD="new_lead";

        //Creating New Lead Table Columns
        private static final String KEY_NEW_LEAD_ID ="id"; 
        private static final String KEY_NEW_LEAD_NAME ="name"; 
        private static final String KEY_NEW_LEAD_EMAIL ="email";
        private static final String KEY_NEW_LEAD_MOBILE="mobile";
        private static final String KEY_NEW_LEAD_Product="define_products";
        private static final String KEY_NEW_LEAD_BUDGET="budget";
        private static final String KEY_NEW_LEAD_PRIORITY="priority";
        private static final String KEY_NEW_LEAD_STATUS="status";
        private static final String KEY_NEW_LEAD_NOTES="notes";
        private static final String KEY_NEW_LEAD_REMINDER_DATE="reminder_date";
        private static final String KEY_NEW_LEAD_REMINDER_TIME="reminder_time";
        private static final String KEY_NEW_LEAD_ADDtoCONTACTS="add_to_contacts";


        //// SQL Statement to create a New Lead Database.
        static final String CREATE_NEW_LEAD_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE"+TABLE_NEW_LEAD+"("+KEY_NEW_LEAD_ID+"integer primary key autoincrement,"+KEY_NEW_LEAD_NAME+"TEXT,"+KEY_NEW_LEAD_EMAIL+"TEXT,"+ KEY_NEW_LEAD_MOBILE+"TEXT,"+KEY_NEW_LEAD_Product+"TEXT,"+KEY_NEW_LEAD_BUDGET+"TEXT,"+KEY_NEW_LEAD_PRIORITY+"TEXT,"+KEY_NEW_LEAD_STATUS+"TEXT,"+KEY_NEW_LEAD_NOTES+"TEXT,"+KEY_NEW_LEAD_REMINDER_DATE+"TEXT,"+KEY_NEW_LEAD_REMINDER_TIME +"TEXT,"+KEY_NEW_LEAD_ADDtoCONTACTS+"TEXT,"+")";

        //Insert New Record In New Lead Table

      public void insert_NewLead_Entry(New_Lead_BeanClass newLead_BeanClass)
      {
          SQLiteDatabase sdb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

          ContentValues contentNewLead_Val=new ContentValues();
          contentNewLead_Val.put(KEY_NEW_LEAD_NAME, newLead_BeanClass.get_Name());
          contentNewLead_Val.put(KEY_NEW_LEAD_EMAIL, newLead_BeanClass.get_Email());
          contentNewLead_Val.put(KEY_NEW_LEAD_MOBILE, newLead_BeanClass.get_MobileNo());
          contentNewLead_Val.put(KEY_NEW_LEAD_Product, newLead_BeanClass.get_Product());
          contentNewLead_Val.put(KEY_NEW_LEAD_BUDGET, newLead_BeanClass.get_Budget());
          contentNewLead_Val.put(KEY_NEW_LEAD_PRIORITY, newLead_BeanClass.get_Priority());
          contentNewLead_Val.put(KEY_NEW_LEAD_STATUS, newLead_BeanClass.get_Status());
          contentNewLead_Val.put(KEY_NEW_LEAD_NOTES, newLead_BeanClass.get_Notes());
          contentNewLead_Val.put(KEY_NEW_LEAD_REMINDER_DATE, newLead_BeanClass.get_Reminder_Date());
          contentNewLead_Val.put(KEY_NEW_LEAD_REMINDER_TIME, newLead_BeanClass.get_Reminder_Time());
          contentNewLead_Val.put(KEY_NEW_LEAD_ADDtoCONTACTS, newLead_BeanClass.get_AddtoContact());

          sdb.insert(TABLE_NEW_LEAD , null , contentNewLead_Val );

          //Close The Database Connection
          sdb.close();

      }

}
```

This Database Helper class

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

   public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,CursorFactory factory, int version) 
        {
                   super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) 
        {
              _db.execSQL(DataBase_Adapter.CREATE_NEW_LEAD_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) 
        {
                   Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +_oldVersion + " to "  
                           +_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
                _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DataBase_Adapter.TABLE_NEW_LEAD);

                onCreate(_db);
        }

    }




        /******************************Submit Detail Button***********************************************/

        dbHandller=new DataBase_Adapter(this);
        dbHandller=dbHandller.open();

        btn_NewLead_Submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.newLead_buttonSubmit);
        btn_NewLead_Submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                strContactName   =eText_newLeadName.getText().toString().trim();
                strContactEmail  =eText_newLeadEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                strContactMobile =eText_newLeadMobile.getText().toString().trim();
                strBudget        =eText_newLeadBudget.getText().toString().trim();
                strNotes         =eText_newLeadNotes.getText().toString().trim();
                strDate          =eText_newLeadDate.getText().toString().trim();
                strTime          =eText_newLeadTime.getText().toString().trim();

                New_Lead_BeanClass  new_Lead_BeanClass = new New_Lead_BeanClass();

                new_Lead_BeanClass.set_Name(strContactName);
                new_Lead_BeanClass.set_Email(strContactEmail);
                new_Lead_BeanClass.set_MobileNo(strContactMobile);
                new_Lead_BeanClass.set_Product(selectedProductItem);
                new_Lead_BeanClass.set_Budget(strBudget);
                new_Lead_BeanClass.set_Priority(selectedPriorityItem);
                new_Lead_BeanClass.set_Status(selectedStatusItem);
                new_Lead_BeanClass.set_Notes(strNotes);
                new_Lead_BeanClass.set_Reminder_Date(strDate);
                new_Lead_BeanClass.set_Reminder_Time(strTime);
                new_Lead_BeanClass.set_AddtoContact(strToggleVlaue);

                dbHandller.insert_NewLead_Entry(new_Lead_BeanClass);

                System.out.println("Data Inserted InTO Sqlite DataBase");

            }
        });


    }
        /******************************Load Spinner Data***********************************************/
        private void loadSpinnerData()
        {
                // database handler
                DbHelper db = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());

                // Spinner Drop down elements
                List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();

                // Creating adapter for spinner
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

                // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                // attaching data adapter to spinner
                spinner_Products.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        }
```

Here is my Log cat stack trace

```
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864): Error inserting budget=89999999 reminder_time=11 : 18 add_to_contacts=true status=closed email=j@g.c priority=medium name=jersey define_products=jaguar reminder_date=1-1-2014 notes=Tmg technology where message gateway technology mobile=1122334455
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: new_lead: , while compiling: INSERT INTO new_lead(budget, reminder_time, add_to_contacts, status, email, priority, name, define_products, reminder_date, notes, mobile) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1149)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1569)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at com.lead_management_project.DataBase_Adapter.insert_NewLead_Entry(DataBase_Adapter.java:188)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at com.lead_management_project.New_Lead_Activity5$9.onClick(New_Lead_Activity5.java:380)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-29 11:21:03.431: E/Database(16864):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you created/updated/modified tables after the initial database creation, you need to update the database version number. Update the version number, recompile and try again.

Comment: table has not created because you had not add space between variable and variabe name. Try like this..CREATE_USERNAMEPASSWORD_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_UsernamePassword + "("+ USERNAMEPASSWORD_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + USERNAMEPASSWORD_KEY_WEBTITLE + " TEXT,"+ USERNAMEPASSWORD_KEY_WEBPASSWORD + " TEXT,"+USERNAMEPASSWORD_KEY_WEBNAME+" TEXT,"+ USERNAMEPASSWORD_KEY_WEBURL +" TEXT,"+ USERNAMEPASSWORD_KEY_WEBTYPE + " TEXT,"+ USERNAMEPASSWORD_KEY_WEBIMAGE + " INTEGER"+")";

Comment: @drunkenRabbit I update the database version number = 4. And the data is inserted properly.Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this..
change your static final String CREATE_NEW_LEAD_TABLE.

```
 CREATE_USERNAMEPASSWORD_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_UsernamePassword + "("
+ USERNAMEPASSWORD_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," 
+ USERNAMEPASSWORD_KEY_WEBTITLE + " TEXT,"
+ USERNAMEPASSWORD_KEY_WEBPASSWORD + " TEXT,"
+ USERNAMEPASSWORD_KEY_WEBNAME+" TEXT,"
+ USERNAMEPASSWORD_KEY_WEBURL +" TEXT,"
+ USERNAMEPASSWORD_KEY_WEBTYPE + " TEXT,"
+ USERNAMEPASSWORD_KEY_WEBIMAGE + " INTEGER"+");";
```

Comment: are u running the app on emulator or on device?

Comment: Running the app On Emulator.